# stored procedure expect some input though its provided

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am stuck in a problem. i am getting error "Procedure or function 'SP_RPT_User' expects parameter '@deptName', which was not supplied." in c# application while parameter is provided. even i copied and replaced the name. still no success.

```
 public DataTable SP_RPT_User(int loggedid, String deptName, String OfficeName, String empType)
    {
        int updatedrows = 0;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SP_RPT_User", connection);
            cCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cCommand.Parameters.Add("@loggedId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = loggedid;
            cCommand.Parameters.Add("@deptName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = deptName;
            cCommand.Parameters.Add("@OfficeName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = OfficeName;
            cCommand.Parameters.Add("@empType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = empType;


            cCommand.CommandTimeout = 90000;
            connection.Open();
            updatedrows = cCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cCommand))
            {
                cCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Fill(table);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            connection.Close();
            // return -100;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return table;

    }
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_RPT_User]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@loggedId int,
@deptName NVarChar(200),
@OfficeName varchar(150),
@empType varchar(150)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql ='SELECT ...'; // here is one query

    if(@deptName != '')
        set @sql = @sql + ' and dbo.TB_Department.name like ''%'+@deptName+'%''';

    Declare @params nvarchar(500)
    SELECT @params ='@loggedId int,'+
    '@deptName NVarChar(200),'+
    '@OfficeName varchar(150),'+
    '@empType varchar(150)'


     exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@loggedId,@deptName,@OfficeName,@empType;


END
```

Can anyone help. thanks in advance.
i am using sql server 2014 and vs2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The educated guess I have is that `deptName` value in C# is `null` while you execute the query. In such case you should pass `DBNull.Value` to have null as parameter value:

```
var param = cCommand.Parameters.Add("@deptName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
param.Value = deptName ?? DBNull.Value;
```

From your procedure I see that you compare with empty string so use `?? string.Empty` to satisfy that condition.

Comment: yes you are right deptName in C# is equal to null. but it will not always be null. if user want to put any value for filtering then i have to apply filter on deptName.

Comment: That choice does not matter now. At the moment you have `null` you need to set parameter value to anything else than C# null to eliminate the exception. `??` operator will do just that - use second value if first is `null`.